# How Can I Filtering Using NSMutableArray and UISearchController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsmutablearray, uisearchcontroller

I'm working on an iOS application using **Swift** and I'm using **NSMutableArray**, and when I try to add UISearchController to my UITableViewController It give me this error

[1.1 click here, please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkyxB.png)

But when I try to do it with NSArray it works great.

If you wondering about Why am I using NSMutableArray?
Because I need it to pass the object of the NSMutableArray that is in the selected row from the UITableViewController to another UIViewController like this:
[1.2 click here, please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCYp7.png)

What I have to do now, how can I adding search bar? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hack it by converting the mutable array to a nsarray and then using that.

Where your doing the stuff in 1.1 just add before the the self.businessNamesArray line add this line

var regArray = self.businessNamesArray as NSArray as! [String]

then change the self.businessNamesArray line to regArray.filter{ rest of your code here

Comment: I did that: **1)** converting the NSMutableArray to NSArray `var BusinessNamesArray = [String]()`   **2)** Then, using this: `var BusinessNamesArrayAfterConverting = self.BusinessNamesArray as NSArray as! [String]` in the function `prepareForSegue` . But when I try to use it, it give me this error:  _Value of type 'UITableViewController' has no member 'BusinessNamesArrayAfterConverting'_

Comment: I am not following your step 1) your creating a new NSArray called BusinessNmesArray ? are you trying to do this     var BusinessNamesArrayAfterConverting = [String]()  BusinessNamesArrayAfterConverting = self.BusinessNamesArray as NSArray as! [String]

Comment: before I ask `BusinessNamseArray` was NSMutableArray, but after your answer I delete it and did what I wrote in the previous comment. I don't know, that is what I got it. Can you tell me what do you suggest me to do with details?, please.

Comment: does it make sense now ?

Comment: I told you that: it give me this error: Value of type 'UITableViewController' has no member 'BusinessNamesArrayAfterConverting'

Comment: delete everything u did in your first comment and then reread my edited answer

Comment: Ok, but to make sure: you said "You can hack it by converting the mutable array to a nsarray and then using that" is that mean delete `var BusinessNamesArray: NSMutableArray = []` and write `var BusinessNamesArray = [String]()` instead?

Comment: great! thanks ray! I did that then no error. I will complete making search bar and I will see if it work after that.

Comment: thats what this line is doing var regArray = self.businessNamesArray as NSArray as! [String]

Answer (score 0):

If you use regular Swift arrays, which I think is the right idea since you're using Swift, you can get it working if you change your array variable type and fix your array filtering syntax. First, change the array declaration to this:

```
var BusinessNamesArray:[String]?
```

The `filter` function your are using on your `self.BusinessNamesArray` returns a filtered array rather than filtering the array in place (which is what it seems like you want). If you want to replace the content of your `self.BusinessNamesArray`, you would need to do something like this:

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    self.BusinessNamesArray = self.BusinessNamesArray.filter { (business:String) -> Bool in 
        return true
        // You probably want to compare strings here like this instead:
        // guard let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text else {
        //     return false
        // }
        // return business.hasPrefix(searchText)
    }
    // You probably also need to reload your table view at this point:
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Keep in mind though that your `BusinessNamesArray` is now filtered and you can't un-filter it. Instead, you should probably keep a second array of your Strings called something like `searchResults`. Then you can use that for filtering and maintain your original list of business names in the original array. So you would add a class variable called `var searchResults:[String]?` and the search filtering code would change to.

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    self.searchResults = self.BusinessNamesArray.filter { (business:String) -> Bool in 
        guard let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text else {
            return false
        }
        return business.hasPrefix(searchText)
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

When you call `reloadData` on your table view at this point, you will probably want to check and see if your search controller is active in the table view delegate's `numberOfSectionsInTableView` as well other delegate functions and use the `searchResults` array if it is active and the `BusinessNamesArray` if its not--something like:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
        return self.searchResults.count ?? 0
    } else {
        return self.BusinessNamesArray.count ?? 0
    }
}
```

(The `self.resultSearchController` variable is a local instance of `UISearchController`. I'm not sure what you've named yours.)

You'll then use similar code to decide which items to grab for your `prepareForSegue:` code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Guard your variables here so you can return early if they're 
    // not valid
    guard let upcoming = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailsViewController, 
              myindexpath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else {
        return
    }

    var titleString = ""
    if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
        if let searchResults = self.searchResults {
            titleString = searchResults[myindexpath.row]
        }
    } else {
        if let businessNames = self.BusinessNamesArray {
            titleString = businessNames[myindexpath.row]
        }
    }
    upcoming.titleString = titleString

    self.deselectRowAtIndexPath(myindexpath, animated: true)
}
```